# how to count number of radio buttons by name in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button

I want to know how to get number of radio buttons by name in AngularJS using a directive.

```
<label ng-repeat="elements in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">
      <input type="radio" name="phone" ng-model="phone" value="example"> 
</label>

<!--Directive by name (phone), number of radio buttons is 7-->

<label ng-repeat="elements in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]">
      <input type="radio" name="OS" ng-model="OS" value="example"> 
</label>

<!--Directive by name (OS), number of radio buttons is 9-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably assign some value on the scope: `$scope.myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];`. And show the length of the list on the view like: `{{ myList.length }}`.